# Surface Integral over a Tetrahedron: Gauss' Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, surface-integrals

I have a vector field $\vec{u}=(x,z^2,y)$ over a tetrahedron with vertices at $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$ and I need to compute $\int_S\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{S}$, $S$ being the surface of the tetrahedron.

I have already calculated $\int_V(\nabla\cdot\vec{u})dV$, which I have found to be equal to $\frac{1}{3}$, now I need to calculate the previous integral and assumedly show that the answers agree (Gauss' Theorem).

So far I have parameterised the surface to say $\vec{x}_s=(s,t,2-2s-2t)$

Next I find $d\vec{S}$ as such:
$$d\vec{S}=(\frac{\partial{\vec{x_S}}}{\partial{s}}\times\frac{\partial{\vec{x_S}}}{\partial{t}})dsdt$$
Therefore:
$\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{S}=10s^2+16st-16s+8t^2-15t+8$

But, upon calculating the integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1\vec{u}\cdot d\vec{S}dsdt$ I get $\frac{5}{2}$. I'm confident in my first integral, but I don't feel as confident in this one as I feel there may be some theoretical misunderstanding with my parameterisation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget the other faces.

Comment: @user10354138 So I've only accounted for the $z=2-2x-2y$ face, and I need to do separate integrals for the faces corresponding to $x=0,y=0,z=0$?

Comment: @Maksymilian5275 Yep, remember Gauss' Theorem refers to the surface integral over closed surfaces, so you have to do all of the faces and add them up to get the total surface integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector field $\vec u = (x, z^2,y)$ and vertices of tetrahedron are $ A (0,0,0), B (1,0,0)$, $C(0,1,0)$ and $D(0, 0, 2)$.

a) For surface $ABC, z = 0, \vec n = (0, 0, -1)$

So the surface integral, $I_{ABC} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} - y \ dy \ dx = - \frac{1}{6}$

b) For surface $ABD$, $y = 0, \vec n = (0, -1, 0)$

So the surface integral, $I_{ABD} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{2-2x} - z^2 \ dz \ dx = - \frac{2}{3}$

c) For surface $ACD$, $x = 0, \vec n = (-1, 0, 0)$, hence the integral is simply zero.

d) Now for surface $BCD$, $z = 2 - 2x - 2y, \vec n = (2, 2, 1)$

$I_{BCD} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} (2x + 2(2-2x-2y)^2 + y)  \ dy \ dx = \frac{7}{6}$

So when you add them up, it does come to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: You may want to see the other answer.

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks and I checked. The other answer is deleted so cannot comment there now. In $d)$, I am parametrizing the surface as $z = 2 - 2x - 2y$ and taking outward normal vector as $(-f_x, - f_y, 1)$ and there is no need to convert it into unit normal vector as we know when we map $dS$ to area element in XY-plane, it cancels out.